# how to get all value from while loop not just 1st iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

The final is the numpy array with 4 rows and I need to get all value from nested while loop, but this code just returns 1st row of final or 1st iteration of loop.

```
def amir2 (final):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    temp = []
    temp2 = []
    temp3 = []
    while i < len(final):
        while j < len(final):
            cos_lib = coss(final[i] , final[j])
            temp.append(cos_lib)
            j += 1
        temp2.append(temp)
        i += 1
    return temp2
```

Comment: Add your input and expected output to the question. And instead of telling output of while-loop, it will be better to explain what you are doing in while loop. May be there will be better approach to do the same.

Comment: what is `coss()` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for numpy use temp2 = np.append(temp2,temp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide details on the exact format of the numpy array `final` and also what you're trying to do in your loop with the `coss` method.

If final is defined like this:

```
final = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], dtype=np.float64)
```

you can get the array using the `.shape` so you can iterate over all elements of the array as follows:

```
for x in range(0, final.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, final.shape[1]):
        print final[x, y]
```